# Storing message into image

Tags: image, embed, bufferedimage, steganography, argb

I tried to read this paragraph from a website, but i don not understand why "32nd pixel store the bits needed for reconstructing the byte value needed to create the original string."

This is trying to put the message into alpha (transparency)(ARGB)

In this code below, why need to embed both integer and byte

```
 int imageWidth = img.getWidth(), imageHeight = img.getHeight(),
 imageSize = imageWidth * imageHeight;
 if(messageLength * 8 + 32 > imageSize) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Message is too long for the chosen image",
       "Message too long!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return;
   }
   embedInteger(img, messageLength, 0, 0);

   byte b[] = mess.getBytes();
   for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++)
      embedByte(img, b[i], i*8+32, 0);
   }

 private void embedInteger(BufferedImage img, int n, int start, int storageBit) {
   int maxX = img.getWidth(), maxY = img.getHeight(), 
      startX = start/maxY, startY = start - startX*maxY, count=0;
   for(int i=startX; i<maxX && count<32; i++) {
      for(int j=startY; j<maxY && count<32; j++) {
         int rgb = img.getRGB(i, j), bit = getBitValue(n, count);
         rgb = setBitValue(rgb, storageBit, bit);
         img.setRGB(i, j, rgb);
         count++;
         }
      }
   }

private void embedByte(BufferedImage img, byte b, int start, int storageBit) {
   int maxX = img.getWidth(), maxY = img.getHeight(), 
      startX = start/maxY, startY = start - startX*maxY, count=0;
   for(int i=startX; i<maxX && count<8; i++) {
      for(int j=startY; j<maxY && count<8; j++) {
         int rgb = img.getRGB(i, j), bit = getBitValue(b, count);
         rgb = setBitValue(rgb, storageBit, bit);
         img.setRGB(i, j, rgb);
         count++;
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the message length so you know how many pixels to read to extract the message. Because the length of the message can't be predicted, 32 bits (for the first 32 pixels) are allocated.

The functions embedInteger and embedByte are almost similar.

- `embedInteger` deals with embedding the length of the message in the first 32 pixels.
- `embedByte` embeds your message characters, one by one. Every time it is called upon, it takes as an input the next character in your message in byte form, `b[i]`. There, it embeds one bit per pixel, for a total of 8 bits per byte.

Comment: Thank you for reply, embedInteger is to deal with embedding the length of the message in the first 32 pixels?? but how about embedByte??

Comment: Sorry, this is might be a dumb question, why need embedInteger, since we could just embed message one by one by using embedByte.

It is only can embed one bit per pixel?

Comment: because i tried to embed the byte array of binary file(128 byte) to image, but when i tried to extract the byte array, it was not the same one i put it in. Because its too large??

Comment: The difference is subtle. `embedInteger` accepts the message length as an integer (`int n`) and has an embedding limit of 32. `embedByte` accepts the message character in a byte form (`byte b`), which was converted with `byte b[] = mess.getBytes()`. With a slight modification you could have one function for both the messageLength and the message, but the author didn't opt for that.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you tried to do there and why it failed.

Comment: Thank you again. Last question from that website, n=(p-32)/8, why need to minus 32 here.

Comment: It's the same as p = 8*n + 32, where p is the number of pixels in the image and n the number of characters in your message. Each character requires 8 bits to be embedded and you need an additional 32 bits for the message length. So you need to have at least 8*n + 32 pixels in your image. Inversely, if you have p pixels, you have embed at most (p-32)/8 text characters.

Comment: It is really helpful for me.i appreciated.
I try to embed a byte array of binary file since yesterday, but when i extract the byte array, which difference in the previous one.
This is where i am asking this question [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267677/generating-different-result-by-using-lsb

Could you please tell me where i did wrong, thank you.