# Getting/Setting a bit value from image

Tags: java, embed, decode, steganography

Question is based on this [site](http://developeriq.in/articles/2013/feb/28/embedding-messages-in-digital-images-using-java/#c3133).

Could someone explain the meaning of these lines:

```
private int getBitValue(int n, int location) {
      int v = n & (int) Math.round(Math.pow(2, location));
      return v==0?0:1;
 }
```

and

```
private int setBitValue(int n, int location, int bit) {
    int toggle = (int) Math.pow(2, location), bv = getBitValue(n, location);
    if(bv == bit)
        return n;
    if(bv == 0 && bit == 1)
        n |= toggle;
    else if(bv == 1 && bit == 0)
        n ^= toggle;
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  int v = n & (int) Math.round(Math.pow(2, location));
```

`Math.pow(2, location)` raises 2 to the given power.  This is rounded and converted to an integer.  In binary, this will be 00000001 if `location==0`, 00000010 if `location==1`, 00000100 if `location==2`, etc.  (Much better would be `1 << location` which shifts a "1" by a certain number of bits, filling in 0 bits at the right.  Using `Math.pow` will probably try to compute the logarithm of 2 every time it's called.)

`n & ...` is a bitwise AND.  Since the item on the right has just one bit set, the effect is to zero out every bit in `n` except for that one bit, and put the result in `v`.  This means that `v` will be 0 if that one bit is 0 in `n`, and something other than 0 if that bit is `, which means

```
  return v==0?0:1;
```

returns 0 if the bit is clear and 1 if it's set.

```
int toggle = (int) Math.pow(2, location), bv = getBitValue(n, location);
```

`toggle` is set to that `Math.pow` thing I already described.  `bv` is set to the bit that's already in `n`, which is 0 or 1.  If this equals the thing you're setting it to, then we don't need to do anything to `n`:

```
if(bv == bit)
    return n;
```

Otherwise, either we need to set it to 1 (remember that `toggle` will have just one bit set).  `n |= toggle` is the same as `n = n | toggle`.  `|` is a bit-wise OR, so that one bit will be set in `n` and all other bits in `n` will remain the same"

```
if(bv == 0 && bit == 1)
    n |= toggle;
```

Or we need to set the bit to 0.  `n ^= toggle` is the same as `n = n ^ toggle`.  `n` is an exclusive OR.  If we get here, then the bit in `n` is 1, and the bit in `toggle` is 1, and we want to set the bit in `n` to 0, so exclusive OR will change that bit to 0 while leaving every other bit the same:

```
else if(bv == 1 && bit == 0)
    n ^= toggle;
```

Comment: It is a very clear explanation. I need to go back to look at code again, and try to understand it. Thank you all.

Comment: why in the method `setBitValue(int n, int location, int bit)` need to do `getBitValue` again, and this time is using rgb value but message length.

Comment: @JarekHuang That's just the way they implemented it.  To set the bit value, this algorithm gets the current bit value, then looks at three different cases: (1) current bit value = desired value, do nothing; (2) current value is 0, desired = 1; (3) current value is 1, desired = 0.  There are ways to accomplish this without using `getBitValue`: `result = (n & ~toggle) | ((bit == 1) ? toggle : 0)`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The getBitValue just gets the value of a specified bit (on a certain location)

The setBitValue sets the value of a bit on the matched specific location.

These getter/setter methods are usually used for image processing, i.e. if you have a musk and you want to change a specific bit value.

Nothing more or less.

Comment: Sorry to not make it clear. i would like to know the meaning of each line in these two method, and why `setBitValue(int n, int location, int bit)` need to do `getBitValue(n, location);` again.